# DataFrame apply a function to the values in one column to create another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file the contains a date and a value

```
Date, Value
2020-03-18,90.0
.
.
2020-04-10,100.0
```

I am loading this file using read csv and applying a function to the date to convert it to a Quantlib date.

```
pd.read_csv(file_location,header=0,float_precision='round_trip', converters = {'Date': DateList.ql_date_from_str})
```

this gives

```
                    Date  Value
0       March 18th, 2020  90.0
.
.
20      April 10th, 2020  100.0
```

Is there a quick way that, as well as having the Quantlib date I can set the index to be the date during the load?

e.g.

```
                        Date    Value
2020-03-18    March 18th, 2020  90.0
    .
    .
2020-04-10    April 10th, 2020  100.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the index when calling `read_csv` by using `index_col` kwarg:

```
pd.read_csv(file_location,header=0,float_precision='round_trip',
            converters = {'Date': DateList.ql_date_from_str},
            index_col='Date')
```

**But** it will remove that column from the dataframe.

Instead you can do it after calling `read_csv` with `set_index`. Make sure to pass `drop=False` otherwise the column will be removed from the dataframe again:

```
df.set_index('Date', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

It can be done on the same line:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_location,header=0,float_precision='round_trip',
                 converters = {'Date': DateList.ql_date_from_str}).set_index('Date', drop=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

After `pd.read_csv`, duplicate the column:

`df['DateQL']=df['Date']`

Then set the index:

`df.set_index('Date', drop=False, inplace=True)`

Then convert only the column to Quantlib date.

NB: DeepSpace's answer will give you an index with a QuantLib date